# Disable IPython console in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

I use the PyCharm community edition and also IPython. PyCharm automatically recognizes IPython and sets it as the default console ([PyCharm webhelp link](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/ipython.html)), so when in debugging mode, it accepts to runs IPython magic commands, like `list?` or `ls` or `%timeit`.

It is very nice, but I would like to use the plain old python console. Is there a simple way to do that? Note that I do not want to uninstall IPython (which obviously solves my problem) nor do I want to set up a virtualenv.

I use Python 3.3.2, but the problem is the same with 2.7.

Answer (score 30):

Go in `File --> Default Settings`, click `console` , Uncheck `Use IPython, if available`

then go in `File --> Settings`, uncheck `Use IPython, if available`

`Default Settings` and `Settings` are two different options in `File` menu so make sure to follow both

**i am using PyCharm version 3.4 and after doing both the above processes i do not get IPython Console.**

Comment: Attempted this solution on PyCharm 4.0.5. No effect. It looks like PyCharm is buggy -- there is no disabling IPython once it is detected.

Comment: Also confirmed that this solution is not working on PyCharm 4.5.1.

Comment: I installed PyCharm again and this soln still works.

Comment: restart your pyCharm and then the settings above apply

Answer (score 9):

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3 on CentOS 7.2. To disable the use of Ipython for current project. Go to `File-->Settings-->Build, Execution, Deployment-->Console`, uncheck the box **Use Ipython if available**.
[image]

Then close the current python console window and open it again or Rerun it. You should see that plain python is used. In my case, there is **no need to restart Pycharm** for this change to take effect.

Also, if you want to use Ipython instead of plain Python, do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

To give a more up-to-date answer, I am running Pycharm 2021.1.3.

## To disable iPython for all future projects:

`File --> New Projects Settings --> Settings for New Projects...` **--> Build, Execution, Deployment**

click `Console`, Uncheck `Use IPython if available`

## To disable for your the current project:

`File --> Settings` **--> Build, Execution, Deployment**

click `Console`, Uncheck `Use IPython if available`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had uncheck from

**Run --> Edit Configuration --> Uncheck "Run with Python Console**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable "run from python console" **globally**, there is a **template** configuration at the bottom left corner called `Edit configuration templates` in the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog window. You can remove `run from python console` there.