# Pycharm run output does not shown in ipython console but a seperate run tab without ipython

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 4.0.4 and anaconda python installation. When I click run, run output is shown in a run tab which is not ipython console. If I choose code and execute in console result is shown Python console which is ipython console. How can I make run output always shown in python console (which is ipython) not run tab (normal output)?

```
Note: prefeferences->build,execution,deployment->console->Use Ipython if available
```

is already checked.

Comment: I guess your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814560/disable-ipython-console-in-pycharm?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro and make a shortcut key for it.

```
Edit>Macros>Start Macro Recording
```

Then `Ctrl+A > Alt+Shift+E >` `click` either on the `code editor` or `Console Input` to eliminate select all

Save the macro with name and make a shortcut key for it in `Settings>` search for Macros