# Debug fails on pycharm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to Python and trying to run a script using PyCharm. When I run the script, I get the following output

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
-u /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 56230 56231 

/Users/chintan.shah/Documents/python-dev/python-scripts/src/examples/kalman_filter.py 29325

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5:
UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")

Running /Users/chintan.shah/Documents/python-dev/python-scripts/src/examples/kalman_filter.py
PyDev console: using IPython 4.0.0
```

Also when I try to debug, the code does not stop at the debug point and I get the warning

```
IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
```

The script should display some plots but it does not. When I copy-paste the whole file in Python console in PyCharm, everything works.

Comment: Mine gives the same warning, but runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have IPython 4.0 installed. If this is the case, I suggest you downgrading your version. I use Pycharm also and what I did in my case was disabling IPython, as explained in the following link: [Disable ipython console in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814560/disable-ipython-console-in-pycharm)