# How to set ipython profile in PyCharm

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, anaconda

I am using PyCharm IDE with **Anaconda** distribution. 
when I run:`Tools > Python Console...` PyCharm uses ipython console which is part of Anaconda distribution.

But it using a default profile.
I already tried add option `--profile=myProfileName` in Environment variables and in Interpreter options in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console`
But it keeps using default profile.

My question is how to set different `ipython` profile in PyCharm?

Comment: I guess your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814560/disable-ipython-console-in-pycharm?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Go to File > Default settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console and select Use Ipython if available
Go to Run > Edit Configurations and select Show command line afterwards
Tip: Run selected parts of your code with ALT + SHIFT + E

**The details:**

If you've selected Anaconda as the project interpreter, IPython will most likely be the selected console even though it neither looks nor behaves like the IPython console you are used to in Spyder.

I guess you are used to seeing this in Spyder: enter image description here

I'm also guessing that the following is what you're seeing in PyCharm in the Console Window:

enter image description here

Unlike Spyder, PyCharm has no graphical indicator showing that this is an IPython console. So, to make sure it's an IPython console and make it behave more or less like the IPython console you are used to from Spyder, you should try to follow these two steps:

Go to File > Default Settings >  Build, Execution, Deployment > Console and make sure to select Use IPython if available. enter image description here

Go to Run > Edit Configurations and select Show command line afterwards enter image description here

Now you can run selected parts of your code with ALT+SHIFT+E more or less exactly like in Spyder.

If this doesn't do the trick, you should check out these other posts on SO:

Interacting with program after execution

Disable ipython console in pycharm