# How to run a file in IPython console as default instead of terminal?

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I started a new project in PyCharm. I have Anaconda 3.6 installed. So, in PyCharm, I selected the Anaconda python.exe as project interpreter.

When I first ran PyCharm, it used the IPython console as "default" console to run my script. Then I restarted my PC and now PyCharm uses the terminal when I run my scripts. Why? I don't want to use the terminal, coming from Anaconda Spyder IDE. I'm used to IPython, I like it and I want to use it.

How can I completely disable the terminal and use only the IPython console?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Short answer:**

1. Go to `File > Default settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console` and select `Use Ipython if available`
2. Go to `Run > Edit Configurations` and select `Show command line afterwards`

Tip: Run selected parts of your code with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

---

**The details:**

If you've selected `Anaconda` as the project interpreter, IPython will most likely be the selected console even though it neither looks nor behaves like the `IPython console you are used to in Spyder`:

[image]

Unlike Spyder, `PyCharm has no graphical indicator` showing that this is an IPython console.

[image]

To  make sure it's an IPython console and make it behave more or less like the IPython console you are used to from Spyder, you should follow these two steps:

1. Go to `File > Default Settings >  Build, Execution, Deployment > Console` and make sure to select `Use IPython if available`.
   [image]
2. Go to `Run > Edit Configurations` and select `Show command line afterwards`
   [image]

Now you can run selected parts of your code with `ALT+SHIFT+E` more or less exactly like in Spyder.

If this doesn't do the trick, you should check out these other posts on SO:

[Interacting with program after execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207019/interacting-with-program-after-execution)

[Disable ipython console in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814560/disable-ipython-console-in-pycharm)

Comment: I you are using a virtualenv make sure to install ipython to this virtualenv also since the above setting won't be applied (*Use IPython **if** available*)

Comment: Great guide. After using this method I started to see different run-time behavior than I expected. Previously when I executed "Run" on a .py document it would run and complete; the stop button would grey out. However, after selecting **show command line afterwards** the program keeps running, and creates a new instance for the same program. Is there anyway to prevent the PyDev console from restarting on every run and creating a new instance?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure actually. By the sound of it, I think you should post that as a new question. For now I can only direct you to a question of my own that may be related to what you are looking for. All the different methods of running and debugging python code is confusing me as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182309/stepwise-debugging-of-selected-python-code  And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261561/why-does-import-pdb-pdb-set-trace-trigger-two-different-debugging-scenarios-whe These are questions more directly related to Spyder though

Comment: ALT + SHIFT + E runs the code in the Python console of Pycharm, but not in the one opened when running a script when you use the option "Show command line afterwards".

Is it possible to run pieces of code likewise in that console were your script was run?

Comment: @rpicatoste. Not sure, unfortunatey. This would also make for a good question in itself.

Comment: Also make sure to have IPython installed in your Conda evironment. When PyCharm creates a new environment, this may not be the case.

Answer (score 5):

**In the new version of Pycharm, you have a different option in Edit Configuration.**

Go to `Run > Edit Configurations` and select `Run with Python console`

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default?

Comment: @Jonno_FTW Once you do above, by default python file will run in IPython console.