# Another kind of TypeError occurs after fixing a TypeError in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Sorry if this is a repeat question - I'm not that good at Python, and the other answers haven't really helped me.

I have a python script: `plink2treemix.py` which is called from the command line like so:

```
plink2treemix.py data.vcf.frq.strat.gz treemix.gz
```

This is the script (it's long but there are two areas that are causing the issue, which I've hashtagged):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os, gzip

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("plink2treemix.py [gzipped input file] [gzipped output file]")
    print("ERROR: improper command line")
    exit(1)
infile = gzip.open(sys.argv[1], "rb") 
outfile = gzip.open(sys.argv[2], "w")


pop2rs = dict()
rss = list()
rss2 = set()

line = infile.readline()
line = infile.readline()
while line:
    line = line.strip().split()
    rs = line[1]
    pop = line[2]
    mc = line[6]
    total = line[7]
    if rs not in rss2: 
        rss.append(rs)
    rss2.add(rs)
    if pop not in pop2rs: 
        pop2rs[pop] =  dict() #FIRST TYPE ERROR
    if pop2rs[pop] in (rs)==0:
        pop2rs[pop][rs] = " ".join([mc, total])
    line = infile.readline()
print("reached end of while loop")

pops = pop2rs.keys()
for pop in pops:
    print >> outfile, pop,
print(outfile, "")
print("printed outfile")

for rs in rss:
    for pop in pops:
        tmp = pop2rs[pop]['rs'].split #SECOND TYPE ERROR
        c1 = int(tmp[0])
        c2 = int(tmp[1])
        c3 = c2-c1
        print >> outfile, ",".join([str(c1), str(c3)]),
    print(outfile, "")
print("programme finished")
```

The first `TypeError` is:

```
line 31, in <module>
    if pop2rs[pop] in (rs)==0:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict
```

I solved this by changing the `dict()` in the line above to `str()`.

This results in a different TypeError later in the code:

```
    tmp = pop2rs[pop][rs]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Which I'm not sure how to fix, as `rs = line[1]` of the input file and is already an int value, the header of the file is below:

```
CHR           SNP     CLST   A1   A2      MAF    MAC  NCHROBS
  22   22:17049382        0    T    C        0      0        2 
  22   22:17049382        1    T    C        0      0        2 
  22   22:17049382        2    T    C        0      0        2
```

I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: the second type error occurs because you are trying to access a location from a key in a string although only dict and operators overloaded objects can access value in memory from string keys.

Comment: Many of the lines here are confusing as to what you expect the input to be and what you expect the output to be. Have a look at [Stepwise debugging of selected Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48212857/7835267) and step through your code at each stage to see if what you expect is what you're actually getting

Comment: @R.LM Thanks for the clarification! But then how do I solve the errors? Sorry if I'm being dumb, just not that experienced in python just yet

Comment: @hemr3 could you explain the point of the `pop2rs` object so that we know whether its values should be `string` or `dict` and then adapt the first or the second part of trhe code so it works

Comment: @R.LM pop2rs acts as a placeholder dict() for the input file, I believe

Comment: apparently, `pop`  is not a string (or not always at least that's what causes your first error. I think it might fix your first type error, and you shall take your code back to where it was before changing `dict()` to `str()`