# Pycharm - Enable word wrap in debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm 2017.3's debugger, when I print a big dictionary for example it is all on one line. I want this dictionary to wrap so I can see more of it. I believe previous versions of PyCharm had this wrapping behaviour. I've looked through the settings and i can only find word wrap for the editor.

Comment: can you provide your example output?

Comment: Cannot really show you output. In the debugger console window, long lists and dictionaries will just be on one line that I have to scroll horizontally to see. In previous versions these outputs would be somewhat pretty printed if I recall correctly.

Comment: Do you mean debugger sub window or debugger console ? Both are different .  debugger keeps track of program execution and debugger console shows o/p of current debugger on the go. You can see variables with nice view in `variables` section of debugger. There you only have to click on arrows to expand. pretty printing while debugging on same code screen would distort the current view . May be thats why then remove it?

Comment: I mean debugger console.

Comment: debugger console is just like `run` window , just switch debugger window you will see variables sub window in the RHS

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reason or as result of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137318) soft-warp button been removed from `PyCharm` debugging python console few versions ago. As workaround you need to install `ipython`.  With `ipython` built-in "pretty printer" you will see something like this:
[image]

Comment: How to install ipython on pycharm ?

Comment: @AllenLin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562734/how-to-run-a-file-in-ipython-console-as-default-instead-of-terminal